# How to updates the value of Map in a List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this type of list

```dart
List<Map> data = [{1: false}, {2: false}, {5: false}, {6: false}]
```

I want to updates only true false values

```dart
List<Map> afterUpdates= [{1: true}, {2: false}, {5: false}, {6: true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following simple 3 steps

1. Find the element to update
2. Find the index of that element in your array and update it
3. Replace the element in array using the index you found

here is a simple logic for it you can test it at [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev)

```
void main() {
 List<Map<int, bool>> data = [{1: false}, {2: false}, {5: false}, {6: false}];
  
  updateKey(key,val){
    print("before");
    print(data);
    var element= data.firstWhere((k)=>k.keys.contains(key),orElse:()=>{});
    var index = data.indexOf(element);
     print("index");
    print(index);
    element.update(key,(v)=>val);
    data[index]=element;
    print("after");
    print(data);
  }
  updateKey(1,true);
  updateKey(6,true);
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data.update(index, (value) => true);
```

Change the index via loop